# How to return all the rows in tracker_sessions table using antonioribeiro/tracker

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using [antonioribeiro/tracker](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) for my website analytics.
Everything is working as intended but I want to count all the rows in tracker_sessions table, when I do

```
$sessions = Tracker::sessions();
return count($sessions);
```

It returns only the number of rows created today.
How would I return all the rows in tracker_sessions table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, you can do this to get more sessions:

```
$sessions = Tracker::sessions(60 * 24 * 365 ); // get sessions (visits) from the past 365 days
```

.., or any number of minutes you want.

You can also use Query Builder to count the table directly:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$sessions = DB::table('tracker_sessions')->count();
```

Comment: I do not know why Tracker::sessions(60 * 24 * 365 )  this query does not updates the result instantly, and sometimes gives less number of rows than actual

Comment: Counting the table is definitely much more efficient... @PrakashPoudel

Comment: Yes it is more efficient, but i was not updating instantly because cache_enabled was true in config file, so it was loading from the cache instead of updating instantly